# Can I use my own domain with c9.io?

Tags: cloud9-ide

The service (c9.io) is great, but I've been looking through the site and can't find the option to have my own domain instead of the automatic subdomain they assign (I don't necessarily mean free).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. It's a dev environment, so the workspace will also be shutdown at some point if no-one is logged in. Easiest is to deploy to f.e. Heroku or DigitalOcean.

Comment: It's a shame. You can in www.nitrous.io but I like the environment in Cloud 9 more.

Comment: This feature has been requested a lot. We are working on always-on workspaces and will allow custom domains as well. Follow @Cloud9IDE for updates on this.

Comment: @RubenDaniels Hi! Is there currently any solution for it?