# Subdomain on Cloud 9 Rails App

Tags: cloud9-ide

I just started using Cloud 9 with my app. Part of my app has an API that is accessed through a subdomain - api.domain. I was curious if anyone was able to access a subdomain through the application C9 creates when running your rails server?

```
rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

A rep from c9.io commented on a similar question here: [Can I use my own domain with c9.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581600/can-i-use-my-own-domain-with-c9-io)

As of now, they still don't support this.